# Visual Studio: File Open / Open Solution: very slow until dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2015

On my machine I have VS 2010, VS 2013 and VS 2015.

But only in VS 2015 when I use "File Open" icon or File -> Open Solution it takes about 20 seconds for the File Dialog to actually show.

And not just after first starting VS. Every time I use it.

Any ideas what it might be? If it were due to something on the file system, wouldn't that show on other program's (especially older VSes) too?

Comment: I am experiencing the very same thing (VS2015 Update 1 and VS2015 Update 2). The `Add -> New Item` or `Add -> Class` dialog is sooooo slow. Sometimes I just want to add a new POCO class to my project and it takes ages using the dialog - might have even forgotten the name of the class by the time the dialog is ready for me to just give it a filename!!! It's actually faster to just create the file using `Windows Explorer -> New -> Text Document -> rename it to xyz.cs` so on a new project that I am working on, I'm rather keeping a copy of Windows Explorer open on a second screen.